# how to limit the website can only be accessed via mobile in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want my website can only be accessed via mobile.
I use CodeIgniter framework.

```
$this->user-agent->moblie()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you'll use the User Agent library.

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/user_agent.html

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
if(!$this->agent->is_mobile())
{
    exit('Mobiles only');
}
```